# # Anchor not working with php "id"

Tags: php, jquery, html, scrollable

I'm working on a scrollable one-page website, in which each div represents a different section. For example, url is dynaone.com/index.php, and when I click on the menu's different buttons, it changes to /index.php#s1, #s2, #s3, and so on. In section nº 2 I added another menu that works with php GET, in a way that when you click on one of the buttons, it redirects you to index.php?id=1 and so on. Of course when I first tried it, it scrolled me back to the top of the page, 'home', as I wasn't specifying the section. But when I did, assigning "index.php?id=1#s2" to the first element in the inner menu, it redirected me to section 1. It doesn't matter which number I write after "#s", it will keep putting section nº 1 on top of the page.
I'm using SMINT's demo as a base, adjusting it to my website's needs, but I couldn't find anything related to GET method issues on the plugin's page. 
I would really appreciate some help with this, as it's very annoying having to go back everytime I click to correctly view section nº 2.

 
This is part of my inner menu:

```
        <div id="botonera_productos"><ul>
        <li><a href="index.php?id=1#s2"> Quemadores</a> </li>
        <li><a href="index.php?id=2#s2"> BCAAs</a></li> </ul> </div>
```

This is my php section:

```
if(@$_GET['id']==1) {
                ?>

                <figure><img src="imagenes/quemadores/1.jpg"><figcaption> ULTIMATE L-CARNITINA 500 60 TABS - <b>$330</b> </figcaption></figure> 
<?php } ?>
```

And this  is the site's main menu:

```
<nav class="subMenu" >
    <div class="inner">
        <a href="#sTop" class="subNavBtn">Home</a>
        <a href="#s1" class="subNavBtn">Nosotros</a> 
        <a href="#s2" class="subNavBtn">Productos</a>
        <a href="#s3" class="subNavBtn">Local</a>
        <a href="#s4" class="subNavBtn">Envíos</a>
        <a href="#s5" class="subNavBtn">Consultas</a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dynaone" class="subNavBtn extLink end" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Anything after the `#` is not sent to PHP.

Comment: @JohnConde Thank you for your answer. So, is there a way to do what I want to do and avoid this issue?

Comment: yup, jsut dont use them

Comment: @Dagon is there an alternative to # to specify a section in the url?

Comment: dont see the php usinging the anchor

Comment: @Dagon, sorry, I don't get what you mean

Comment: i don't really get the question is my problem.

Comment: @Dagon I get index.php?id=1#s2 doesn't lead me anywhere because anything after # is not sent to PHP, as john told me before. So I was asking if there's an alternative to "#s2" to specify that I want the browser to show me a specific section after index.php?id=1 is interpreted.

Comment: but i don't see what php even has to do with it, its not php that uses the # its the browser if the url on the screen shows `index.php?id=1#s2` then you should be sent to the `s2` anchor point

Comment: @Dagon it sends me to s1 no matter what I write, I only say it's related to php as that's what the first answer said

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear but basically:

The anchor is an HTML construct. So once the page is already loaded, you can use `#whatever` to take you to wherever on that page that the anchor has been defined; ala `<a id="whatever">`

The PHP arguments, like `?id=1` - a new page will be loaded depending on what you use here.

You can use anchors in conjunction with a PHP page (ie. a PHP page may have multiple anchors) but you cannot load a new page with anchors alone.

Maybe Javascript will help you achieve what you want to do. With AJAX calls and the like then there are far less restrictions on how you load data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I get it now. Can you explain to me how to use AJAX in this case? I'm new to this topic and I've never used it.

Comment: It may not be required, but if you were to use AJAX you could truly make it a one page website. For example instead of having `?id=1`, `?id=2`, etc you could just have it so when a certain button is clicked the data on the page reloads but the page itself does NOT reload.

Comment: that would be great! I guess I'll just have to learn how to use it